# Google Map: REQUEST_DENIED

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, pyrocms

The map in my localhost is working perpectly fine but a error occurs when i view it in the live version. I'm using geocoder for my dynamic map and the error is REQUEST_DENIED. sensor is set to true. Should I change it to false?

Comment: The sensor parameter is no longer required.  Are you including a key, enabled for that domain and the geocoder?

Comment: No key is included. Should I put a key? The website is still in the client staging for them to test it. I still dont know that domain will be used so I'm not sure if I will get a appropriate key.

Comment: Keys are now required for _all_ new maps (except temporarily on file:// and maybe localhost).

Answer (score 1):

Goto google developer console (http://code.google.com/apis/maps/) and check whether the API KEY corresponding to your app has privileges for the requests from your live URL. 
This would be helpful if you're to create a new key
http://chrisholtz.com/blog/getting-started-with-the-google-maps-api/

Comment: The website I'm developing is still in the client staging for them to test it out? The url is still for testing and will not be used for the official website. And creating a key needs the project

Comment: Just create a key with your account and replace it later with the customer key when it goes live...